# Jquery $.get call to servlet not returning any values

Tags: java, jquery, http, servlets

I'm attempting to use jquery to send information to a servlet and receive a response from the servlet. I know my problem is not with the servlet because when I paste the url

```
http://localhost:8080/WebPaymentSolution?secureToken=abcd1234569780jfhgutinjhuyikfj746534&user=Conner
```

I get the proper response back in the browser. Here is the complete jquery code I am using.

```
$.get(
"http://localhost:8080/WebPaymentSolution",
{ secureToken : 'abcd1234569780jfhgutinjhuyikfj746534', user : 'Conner' },
function( data ) {
$( '#hss_iframe' ).html( data );
}
);
```

I  am currently not getting a response back from the servlet.

Comment: A stupid question: is your javascript code loaded also from your servlet container?

Comment: No. It's totally separate from the servlet container.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually solved this problem but it only works if you have control over the servlet(server side solution). I set the header response the servlet gives back to allow access control from any origin. It's working perfectly now. Here's the line of code I added to make it work.

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

I know this doesn't answer the question of how you do this from jQuery but this is the best solution for me so I am going with it.

Comment: That's however the only way. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

try it with:

`$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  type: 'get'
  success: function(data){alert(data)},
  dataType: dataType
});`

to enshure that you are usign get instead of post

and look with firebug if what happened with the request. if you get a "Permanently Moved" in firefox you are trying to call an ajax request to another domain from wherer you script has loaded

if it is so, google:
Cross-Site-Scripting => XSS

Comment: I tried to edit this answer and add a comma after 'get' but it won't allow me to do an edit that is under 6 characters? Not sure why that is.

Comment: Where in firebug would I see "Permanently Moved"? I've looked all over but I don't see it. It shows I'm sending data to the servlet. I'm just not getting anything in response to that request. I'm aware of XSS issue but I want to make sure that's it if that is really my issue. Thanks.